# How to run a python script with a list of arguments in linux terminal?

Tags: python, linux, shell

I have a list .txt with input arguments from a python script, I would like to execute the script with each argument in the list in the linux terminal, but only runs the latter.

I'm trying this:

`for p in $(cat list.txt); do eval $(echo script.py -u $p); done;`

Comment: Can you provide the content of `list.txt`?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: It's just a list of internet addresses ... None of them have spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are multiple ways to do it. But my most recommended way would be the first one.

1. Change your python script to take an argument which is the path to your `list.txt`. I would suggest using argparse module in python to handle arguments. Once the argument is read, just loop thorugh the contents of the file in python and use them the way you want to. With the you can handle the arguments much better. The program would be more robust.
2. You can run the python script using cat operation on the `list.txt`. `python script.py $(cat list.txt)`
3. You can use `pipe`, `grep` and `awk`. `python script.py $(grep pattern file | awk '{print}' ORS=' ')`

But I would still suggest the first option. Its more robust, you can handle arguments better and control the errors also.